# Break the Hierarchy in a column into multiple columns recursively using SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have single column table that is storing a fixed width file data. I am trying to unpack it into multiple columns in a View by recursively populating the data in the columns in a de-normalized form.

The 4 records below are actually four table records.
Line 1 - Header Record,
Line 2 - Header Data Record,
Line 3 - Data Layout Record,
Line 4 - Data Record

```
  00 00000000000000000000000000 RX  12/2012 FMH99999 ABCDE                   C  EUR 1212-1212      0000003899001982HAP04
  00 00000000000050100001   100100001 Subterritory 100001                        SUBTERRITORY             1000     40      
Z01A00009999900100000000000500IMSIRIN           KAPS                    24          IMSIMSHEALTH         000888888800   
Z01A0000999990011000000    722          +00000000014940+00000006723000+00000000358560000
```

What I am trying to achieve here is in the following Format:
Line 1 | Line 2 | Line 3 | Line 4

Here is what I tried so far but the Line 1 records doesn't get populated in all the records but only in first record. I am looking for ANSI SQL approach (database agnostic).

```
    SELECT  SUBSTRING(DATASET, 28, 1)       AS HEADER_RECORD_LAYOUT_TYPE
        ,   SUBSTRING(DATASET, 29, 2)       AS HEADER_RECORD_DATA_TYPE
        ,   ''                              AS HEADER_DATA_LEVEL
        ,   ''                              AS HEADER_DATA_CODE
        ,   ''                              AS RECORD_LAYOUT_CODE
        ,   ''                              AS RECORD_LAYOUT_DEFINITION_TYPE
        ,   ''                              AS DATA_RECORD_SIGN_FOR_COUNTING_UNITS
        ,   ''                              AS DATA_RECORD_COUNTING_UNITS
    FROM    MY_TABLE
    WHERE   SUBSTRING(DATASET, 28, 1) = '0' --Line 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  ''                              AS HEADER_RECORD_LAYOUT_TYPE
        ,   ''                              AS HEADER_RECORD_DATA_TYPE
        ,   SUBSTRING(DATASET, 17, 2)       AS HEADER_DATA_LEVEL
        ,   SUBSTRING(DATASET, 19, 9)       AS HEADER_DATA_CODE
        ,   ''                              AS RECORD_LAYOUT_CODE
        ,   ''                              AS RECORD_LAYOUT_DEFINITION_TYPE
        ,   ''                              AS DATA_RECORD_SIGN_FOR_COUNTING_UNITS
        ,   ''                              AS DATA_RECORD_COUNTING_UNITS
    FROM    MY_TABLE
    WHERE   SUBSTRING(DATASET, 28, 1) = '1' --Line 2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  ''                              AS HEADER_RECORD_LAYOUT_TYPE
        ,   ''                              AS HEADER_RECORD_DATA_TYPE
        ,   ''                              AS HEADER_DATA_LEVEL
        ,   ''                              AS HEADER_DATA_CODE
        ,   SUBSTRING(DATASET, 1, 5)        AS RECORD_LAYOUT_CODE
        ,   SUBSTRING(DATASET, 28, 1)       AS RECORD_LAYOUT_DEFINITION_TYPE
        ,   ''                              AS DATA_RECORD_SIGN_FOR_COUNTING_UNITS
        ,   ''                              AS DATA_RECORD_COUNTING_UNITS
    FROM    MY_TABLE
    WHERE   SUBSTRING(DATASET, 28, 1) = '5' --Line 3

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  ''                              AS HEADER_RECORD_LAYOUT_TYPE
        ,   ''                              AS HEADER_RECORD_DATA_TYPE
        ,   ''                              AS HEADER_DATA_LEVEL
        ,   ''                              AS HEADER_DATA_CODE
        ,   ''                              AS RECORD_LAYOUT_CODE
        ,   ''                              AS RECORD_LAYOUT_DEFINITION_TYPE
        ,   SUBSTRING(DATASET, 71, 1)       AS DATA_RECORD_SIGN_FOR_COUNTING_UNITS
        ,   SUBSTRING(DATASET, 72, 17)      AS DATA_RECORD_COUNTING_UNITS
    FROM    MY_TABLE
    SUBSTRING(DATASET, 28, 1) = '4' --Line 4
;
```

Comment: What is the maximum number of records in the data? And what is the exact layout of the records (each column width, total width, padding if any)? And is this 4 rows in the table, or 1 row with newlines

Comment: @Charlieface This is four rows in the table. I identify each record with the filter mentioned above. The table has thousands of records. The total length of each record is 121 irrespective of being header/data etc. As far as the length of each column is considered, what I have mentioned above pertains the exact lengths and I am only interested in extracting those columns. Please let me know if you need to knw anything else.

Comment: So why are you using `union all`, why not just select all those columns in one `select`? Are you trying to say that every 4 separate rows are supposed to have some sort of ordering/relationship between one row and the next? SQL tables don't have an inherent ordering, you would need to state how you identify which rows can be collapsed together.

Comment: So, since each line corresponds to the next three lines in this case, I would like to kind of pivot each row into a single row with multiple columns one for each Line. In reality, Line 1 and Line 2 will be one record each in the table while Line 2 and Line 4 can have more than one record.

Comment: Rows 3 and 4 doesn't need to be broken into multiple rows. As mentioned in my original post, Line 1 is header, Line 2 is header_data, Line 3 is data_record_layout and Line 4 is data_record. So, I want Lines 1 through 4 in a single row. Please let me know if that isn't still clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  SUBSTRING(DATASET, 28, 1)       AS HEADER_RECORD_LAYOUT_TYPE
        ,   SUBSTRING(DATASET, 29, 2)       AS HEADER_RECORD_DATA_TYPE
    FROM    MY_TABLE
    WHERE   SUBSTRING(DATASET, 28, 1) = '0' --Line 1
) header1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT  SUBSTRING(DATASET, 71, 1)       AS DATA_RECORD_SIGN_FOR_COUNTING_UNITS
        ,   SUBSTRING(DATASET, 72, 17)      AS DATA_RECORD_COUNTING_UNITS
    FROM    MY_TABLE
    WHERE   SUBSTRING(DATASET, 28, 1) = '4' --Line 4

) data1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT  SUBSTRING(DATASET, 1, 5)        AS RECORD_LAYOUT_CODE
        ,   SUBSTRING(DATASET, 28, 1)       AS RECORD_LAYOUT_DEFINITION_TYPE
    FROM    MY_TABLE
    WHERE   SUBSTRING(DATASET, 28, 1) = '5' --Line 3
) header2
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT  MIN(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DATASET, 28, 1) = '1' THEN SUBSTRING(DATASET, 17, 2) END)   AS HEADER_DATA_LEVEL
        ,   MIN(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(DATASET, 28, 1) = '1' THEN SUBSTRING(DATASET, 19, 9) END)   AS HEADER_DATA_CODE
    FROM    MY_TABLE
    WHERE   SUBSTRING(DATASET, 28, 1) = '2' --Line 2
) data2
;
```

It would be beneficial to have an index on a computed column `SUBSTRING(DATASET, 28, 1)`

Comment: Thank you but CROSS APPLY doesn't seem to be available in Snowflake. We are in the process of migrating from SQL Server to Snowflake (that's why asked for an ANSI SQL based solution in my original post) and I expected CROSS APPLY would be available in Snowflake but unfortunately not.

Comment: Just realised it's not correlated anyway so can change to `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: Thank you, this is almost close. But, its returning the total number of records based on Line 2 filter and not the total. For example, in my data I have one record for Line 1 filter, 10 records for Line 2 filter, 1 record for Line 3 filter and 15 records for Line 4 filter. So, I am expecting a total of 15 records while it is only returning 10 records.

Comment: Ah ok misunderstood. Have swapped them round now. Maybe I'm not getting it, how do you know which of line 2 and 4 relate to each other?

Comment: I flipped earlier that but it only gave me one record. So, thought I must be doing something else to get 15 records.

Comment: I think I found the issue. If I flip the query for Line 4 filter into header2 subquery, I am getting the right number of records. If you can make that change in your answer, I'll mark it as Answer for this question. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You can actually [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66190847/edit) it yourself, would be easier because I'm unclear which ones you mean